# Having ElasticSearch ignore filter when field does not exist

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running a query against an alias that is currently pointing to a dozen of indexes. Not all documents have the same structure across these indexes, so I am trying to run a filtered query:

```
     "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [ { 
              "term" : { "channel" : "24" }
            },
            {
              "range" : {
                "startTime" : { "gt" : "now" }
              }
           }]
       }
     }
```

ElasticSearch is filtering all documents that have channel 24, but I would also want all the other document that do not have the attribute channel. For example, my query should bring all actors (doc doesnt have properties channel and startTime), movies (doc doesnt have properties channel and startTime), genres (doc doesnt have properties channel and startTime) and tv shows/programs (doc has properties channel and startTime) that air on channel 24.

Is there a way to do that without involving filter script? I could achieve this using script but then the performance of the query would be really bad.

Thank you
Thiago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "channel": "24"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "range": {
                           "startTime": {
                              "gt": "now"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                     {
                        "exists": {
                           "field": "channel"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "exists": {
                           "field": "startTime"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sloan, it didnt work. I ran the filter against the index that contain tv shows/programs and did not return any document.

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to diagnose the problem unless you can provide some example data. Ideally, the data should be simplified so as to retain the essence of your problem but not full of extraneous stuff, and still varied enough to make it clear what you expect to be returned and what you don't. You might want to put it in a gist or something.

Comment: If you could provide the data already packaged into a bulk request (something like [this](http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d5625c80946f332718b0fa166bba27efd264b76e)), even better.

Comment: let me prepare the gist and send it to you! Thank you

Comment: Hi @Sloan, here is the gist: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/6abc79ab5fb6d4470241e5e1013f7aba930ad9fe

Comment: Okay, so you specified `"type"` as a property of each document. This is different than the `"_type"` metadata field that Elasticsearch uses. The `"_type"` of each document is `"doc"`, the way you have the data set up, and `"type"` is just another property. Is that what you meant to do? Also, is `"startTime"` a date ([which kind?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-date-format.html)) or a long?

Comment: Hi @Sloan, I am using spring-data-elasticsearch, my pojo is a Date object but the data is being saved as timestamp (not sure why) but it works for my use case as timestamp.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/9e480d4e6934321461900d880b115347a99ac485. The query I posted above seems to work with the data you provided (once I specified that `"startTime"` is a `"date"` field so I could use `"now"` in the query.

Comment: Hi @Sloan, it seems to be working! Thank you. These two filters are mandatory filters, now I am trying to add the dynamic filters the user can create. These dynamic filters should have their own "should" clause?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96589/discussion-between-thiago-and-sloan-ahrens).

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of structure... maybe curly hell?